# Compiler optimizations for infinite lists in Haskell?

Tags: performance, optimization, haskell, ghc

I've various "partial permutation" functions of type `t -> Maybe t` that either take me to a new location in a data structure by returning a `Just` or else return a `Nothing` if they cannot yet get there.

I routinely must applying these partial permutations in repeated specific patterns, building a list of all intermediate values, but truncating the list whenever I return to my starting position or a permutation fails.

```
scan_partial_perms :: Eq t => [t -> Maybe t] -> t -> [t]
scan_partial_perms ps v = map fromJust . takeWhile test $ scanl (>>=) (Just v) ps
   where  test (Just i) | i /= v = True
          test _ = False

iterate_partial_perm = scan_partial_perm . iterate
cycle_partial_perms = scan_partial_perms perms . cycle
```

I'm fairly confident that `scanl` has the desirable strictness and tail recursion properties in this context.  Any other tips on optimizing this code?  In particular, what compiler options beyond `-O3 -fllvm` should I read about?

At worst, I could replace the `scanl` and infinite list with an accessor function defined like

```
perm l i = l !! i `rem` length l
```

I'd imagine this cannot improve performance with the right optimizations however.

Comment: `-O3` means the same thing as `-O2`.

Comment: Thanks!  Also, should I have posted this to codereview.SE instead?

Comment: I think it's a pretty good fit for SO because the question is fairly concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a bug in `scan_partial_perms`,

```
scan_partial_perms ps v = map fromJust . takeWhile test $ scanl (>>=) (Just v) ps
```

`scanl f s list` always starts with `s`, so `takeWhile test (scanl ...)` is `[]`. If that is intentional, it's quite obfuscated. Assuming what you want is

```
scan_partial_perms ps v = (v:) . map fromJust . takeWhile test . tail $ scanl (>>=) (Just v) ps
```

there's not much you can do. You can `{-# SPECIALISE #-}` it so the `Eq` dictionary is eliminated for the specialised-for types. That'll do you some good if the compiler doesn't do that on its own (which it may if it can see the use site). With ghc >= 7, you can instead make it `{-# INLINABLE #-}`, so that it can be specialised and perhaps inlined at each use site.

I don't know what happens down the llvm road, but at the core-level, `map`, `fromJust` and `takeWhile` are not yet inlined, so if you're desperate enough, you can get maybe a few tenths of a percent by inlining them manually if they aren't inlined later in the llvm backend:

```
scan_partial_perms ps v = v : go v ps
  where
    go w (q:qs) = case q w of
                    Just z
                      | z /= v -> z : go z qs
                    _ -> []
    go _ _      = []
```

But those are very cheap functions, so the gains - if at all present - would be small.

So what you have is rather good already, if it's not good enough, you need a different route of attack.

The one with the list indexing,

```
perm l i = l !! (i `rem` length l)
-- parentheses necessary, I don't think (l !! i) `rem` length l was what you want
```

doesn't look good. `length` is expensive, `(!!)` is expensive too, so both should in general be avoided.

Comment: Oops yes the version I wrote would've failed.  I'll check out specialise and inlinable, thanks!